# How do I combine two or more values output in LessR PC function for Donut Charts?

Tags: r, donut-chart

I am trying to create a donut chart with the lessR PieChart (PC) function, but I am stuck at finding a way to combine two or more values options to show in the chart. For instance, I would like for the values to show as counts and percentages at the same time. E.g., 10 (2%)

but the values argument seems to only allow % or counts or prop at one time but does not seem to allow combining argument options. I have tried using c to combine "input" and "%" but it didn't work. I have also tried paste0, & and | but nothing seems to work.

Below is an example code to recreate the problem using the lessR package:

```
    # install.packages(lessR)
library(lessR)

# Sample data of the package
data <- rd("Employee")

# Donut chart
PieChart(Dept, data = data,
         fill = "viridis",
         values = "input",
         main = NULL)


  # install.packages(lessR)
library(lessR)

# Sample data of the package
data <- rd("Employee")

# Donut chart
PieChart(Dept, data = data,
         fill = "viridis",
         values = "%",
         main = NULL)
```

I want my values to show as both input and percentages, e.g., 15 (20%). If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure showing both input and percentage onlt using `PieChart` function, as I take a look at source code of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `ggplot` for creating a pie-chart. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  group_by(Dept) %>%
  summarise(value = n()) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=value, fill=Dept)) +
  geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value, " (", scales::percent(value / sum(value)), ")")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

#### Comment:

Maybe you want something like this using `geom_label_repel`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
data %>%
  group_by(Dept) %>%
  summarise(value = n()) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(value))), 
         pos = value/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), value/2, pos)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=value, fill=Dept)) +
  geom_bar(width=1, stat="identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y = pos, label = paste0(value, " (", scales::percent(value / sum(value)), ")", Dept)), size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

#### Comment: Donut chart

You can create donut charts in `ggplot2` using `coord_polar` and `geom_col`. The variable `hsize` determines the size of the hole in the chart. You can use the following code:

```
hsize <- 1

library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
data %>%
  group_by(Dept) %>%
  summarise(value = n()) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(value))), 
         pos = value/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), value/2, pos)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hsize, y=value, fill=Dept)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  xlim(c(0.2, hsize + 0.5)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y = pos, label = paste0(value, " (", scales::percent(value / sum(value)), ")", Dept)), size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to make a donut chart, showing both percentages and numbers as well as having the labels outside. Thanks.

Comment: @ScholarCCE, I added some code for creating the percentages and numbers with labels outside of the piechart.

Comment: Thanks, @Quinten. Do you know how I can turn this into a donut chart rather than a pie chart? I need this exact thing in a donut chart. Thank you!

Comment: @ScholarCCE, I added some code for a Donut chart! You can change the size of the hole by `hsize`.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help, thanks!